# Filtering to rows with only complete cases for certain columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that I would like to subset where col1, col2, and col3 are all not null. How can I do this with the filter function in dplyr?

I think I can do so like this with `drop_na()` but i want a solution with `filter()`

```
df %>% tidyr::drop_na(col1,col2,col3)
```

Comment: "drop_na()" is in the tidyr package and not dplyr.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `if_all`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   filter(if_all(c(col1, col2, col3), complete.cases))
```